# PHP Mail not showing HTML in Switch Statement

Tags: php, email, switch-statement

I have a form with all the submissions going to one person but also sends a copy to another person responsible for the State that the user chose with the switch statement.  The notification email that goes the the main admin looks fine (html is generated) but the ones in the switch statement are showing as plain text and show the HTML tags.  Any idea how to fix this?  Thank you.

```
//after user registers send notification to admin
$to = 'admin@email.com'
$subject = 'subject';
$message = "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div align='left'>
<strong>New Registration Information:</strong><br />
<br />
<table cellspacing=\"4\" cellpadding=\"4\" align=\"left\">
<tr>
<td><strong>Username:</strong></td>
<td>".$userInput."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Password:</strong></td>
<td>".$passInput."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Email:</strong></td>
<td>".$emailInput."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>First Name:</strong></td>
<td> ".$fnameInput."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Middle Name:</strong></td>
<td>".$mnameInput."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Last Name:</strong></td>
<td>".$lnameInput."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Job Title:</strong></td>
<td>".$jobtitleInput."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Company</strong></td>
<td>".$companyInput."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Address:</strong></td>
<td>".$addressInput."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>City:</strong></td>
<td>".$cityInput."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>State:</strong></td>
<td>".$stateInput."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Zip:</strong></td>
<td>".$zipInput."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Phone Number:</strong></td>
<td>".$phoneInput."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Registered State:</strong></td>
<td>".$registeredstateInput."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Membership Level:</strong></td><td>";
if($membershipLevel == 1)
    $message .= "Level 1 Here</td></tr></table></div></html>";
else if($membershipLevel == 2)
    $message .= "Level 2 Here</td></tr></div></html>";

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

//now send email to State contact
switch($registeredstateInput){
 case "AZ":
  $to = 'emailaddress1@email.com';
  break;
 case "AR":
  $to = 'emailaddress2@email.com';
  break;
 case "CA":
  $to = 'emailaddress3@email.com';
  break;
}
//if that state doesn't have a contact, don't send email
if($to != 'admin@email.com')
{
mail($to, $subject, $message);
}
```

Comment: You need to show the rest of the code - where you build and send the message - as well.

Comment: Added code for message.

Comment: No, the code after you set the address for the second message.

Comment: Added.  Is it because I don't have $headers on the last mail()?

Comment: Yes, just add the headers and it should work.